# Laravel: Datatables + encrypting data optimization

Tags: php, laravel, encryption, optimization, datatable

I have kind of a big issue and i'm trying to find a workaround.
I have a model that has 3 fields automatically encrypted.

I am using Crypt to automatically crypt data when saving values to db and encrypting them when I am getting them. (simple setter/getter)

And this worked just fine when I have had up to 40 records. However now it's over 2,5k and loading this entiretiy of data into datatables is just taking way too much time. I have my serverSideProcessing turned to on,

```
public function getDatatable()
{

    return datatables()->of(DB::table('patients')) //I have to use collection so data is decoded automatically when accessing data
        ->addColumn('name_surname', function($row){
            return $row->name . ' ' . $row->surname;
        })
        ->addColumn('pesel_prop', function($row) {
            return $row->pesel;
        })
        ->make(true);
}
```

Encrypted values are 'pesel', 'surname' and 'address' (that I skipped to make it more readable). How can i possibly make this process quicker?

I tried using cache but entire process of adding a new patient has to be quite dynamic. I also turned on all datatables optimalizations I have found.

Comment: Firstly, do you really want to be encrypting those values? things like `name` and `id number` are usually indexed for searching, I understand what your concern is, but if you are just going to dump the data out in full, all an attacker needs to do is gain access to your data is a valid login. Secondly, is it the query that is taking a long time or rendering the table? You should probably apply a paging system to display a subset of records rather than all of them in one go.

Comment: I have switched from DB::table('patients') to Patient::query() and it speeded it up like 1000 times